# Connect to a local MSSQL server from Apache Airflow using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm trying to connect to my local MS SQL server on my machine using Apache airflow in Docker. I'm new to this and could not find enough documentation on how to proceed with connection.

Please suggest all possible ways to connect to mssql server using Apache airflow in docker.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to run your docker image with option `--net=host`, then you could connect to server the same as you connect on host machine.

Comment: Tried Installing Mssql image and connecting to DB Server using below code which is returning [2020-04-06 23:08:28,382] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - No module named 'pyodbc'.     

import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=10.0.0.185;DATABASE=AdventureWorks2017;UID=SA;PWD=@Irflow2020')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT TOP 10 *  FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]', conn)

Comment: Well that seems to be material for a whole new question.